Do we have complete understanding of $\mathbb N$?
We have some understanding of natural numbers. We have PA theory and we believe that $\mathbb N$ is one of the PA models. But PA can't prove some statements about $\mathbb N$ even though they are true in this specific PA model. And in fact there are no any finite system of axioms which would be able to completely describe $\mathbb N$. All we can do is to specify new axioms to create more complete formal description of $\mathbb N$.
But now here is a question: do we really have complete understanding of natural numbers? Let me put it in other words. Suppose there is a program which asks you a list of questions about $\mathbb N$. And let's suppose that when you answer a question from the list you actually give more precise formal description of $\mathbb N$. And after you answer some questions from the list the program will give you some new axioms based on your answers. The question is whether we can actually answer all questions from this list based only on our "natural" understanding of natural numbers.
There is a trivial example that illustrates that the answer is negative. The example is the question about consistency of theory consisting of all true statements about $\mathbb N$. We can't answer it based only on our "natural" understanding of natural numbers. But let's maybe ignore this question. Will we be able to answer any other question?
If the answer is negative then do I understand correctly that actually we do not understand what natural numbers are? And when we create more strong axiomatic system then we actually come up with more complete understanding of natural numbers?

It's not so easy to ignore incompleteness like that. PA also can't prove results like the "strengthened finite Ramsey theorem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem

@QiaochuYuan yes, we can't formally prove it. But the question is actually about our understanding of natural numbers. Let's suppose that questions from that list I was talking about are formulated as simply as it is possible. And if we will be answering the questions from the list then this will result in that theorem being true of false. Will we be able to answer these questions based only on our "natural" understanding of natural numbers?

Of course we can answer the consistency question. First of all, "the consistency of $\mathbb N$" makes no sense. Consistency is a property of theories, not of models. The question about the "consistency of $\mathsf{PA}$", on the other hand, we can obviously answer positively, since (as you stated in your question) $\mathbb N$ is a model of this theory.

@AndrésE.Caicedo sorry, what I actually meant by consistency of $\mathbb N$ was actually the consistency of the theory which would consist of all true statements about natural numbers. Does this make sense?

Sure, but that theory is obviously consistent, since $\mathbb N$ is a model of it.

@AndrésE.Caicedo it looks like it takes away from the essence of my original question - do we really have complete understanding of what $\mathbb N$ is? i.e. can we actually list those formulas which would be part of the theory consisting of all true statements about $\mathbb N$. Sorry, may be I don't understand something and my question does not make sense, but I yet do not understand why if it is the case.

@user341 We understand what the natural numbers are just fine (at least according the majority view), and likewise what it means for a statement to be true of the natural numbers. Whether we can figure out the truth or falsity of every statement is a different matter.

@spaceisdarkgreen sorry, I can't get your point. If there is a statement which we can't formally prove/disprove (i.e. understand its truth or falsity) then (at least as I understand) it simply means that our theory just lacks some axioms which are needed to formally specify natural numbers precisely enough. And if we really understand what natural numbers are then we can add needed axioms to our theory and after that we will be able to prove or disprove needed statement about natural numbers. Am I wrong?

@user341 My point is that knowing precisely what something is is not tantamount to knowing the answer to every question about it. I can precisely specify who my brother is, but I have no idea what he ate for breakfast this morning. Likewise I can precisely define the natural numbers and I can even axiomatize them uniquely up to isomorphism in 2nd order logic, but that's not going to help me solve the twin prime conjecture. Sure, the natural numbers are not fully specified by (first-order) PA (there are other models), but nobody said that's the definition of the natural numbers.

@user341 (full disclosure: I've overstated the case a bit and there are known philosophical difficulties with defining the natural numbers in a way that is not "morally" circular in some sense. But that's ancillary to the point here that a definite description of something shouldn't be expected to yield a decision procedure for deciding all of its properties.)

@spaceisdarkgreen so if I understand correctly, what you are talking about means that we know what natural numbers are (if omit those philosophical difficulties) and if we do not know weather some statement about natural numbers is true or false it is because of our limited reasoning, so the reasoning is "bottleneck" but not our understanding of natural numbers. Did I get it right?

@user341 Yeah, I don't really take exception to the phrasing that "we don't have a complete understanding of the the natural numbers" in your title, but this lack of understanding isn't about what the natural numbers are, it's about various non-obvious questions one could ask, like Goldbach conjecture, etc. Whether the only limitation is that we simply haven't reasoned well enough thus far or if the barriers from Godel's theorem, etc indicate some absolute limitation to mathematical knowledge is an open question.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Maybe not "complete" in the common sense meaning (not necessarily the "technical" one related to Godel's theorems): if we do not know the answer to the Goldbach conjecture, maybe in the future we will know, and thus our "understanding" of the naturals is growing. See Intuitionism: "The dependence of intuitionism on time is essential: statements can become provable in the course of time and therefore might become intuitionistically valid while not having been so before."

first any program that will ask you to list properties of N what is the criteria of that program to determine if those answers you give are logically consistent and what criteria does it assign to them? if everytime you answer you give a more formal precise answer formal and precise according to what set of axioms? are the questions in the list of the program logical? according to what system? for example the program cant ask you a question like is the set of natural numbers tasty. a complete understanding of natural numbers in what framework? i.e: do you ask why peanos axioms work? is that the least set of axioms that span the natural numbers? this is a philosophical pondering on the phenomenology of understanding number systems not a mathematical or even meta mathematical pondering. hope this helps
